# Why ocaml infers bool type?

Tags: types, ocaml

I have following definition:

```ml
type 'a tree = Leaf | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
```

and function

```ml
let rec is_bst' (t: 'a tree) :[> `Empty | `Failure | `Success of 'a * 'a ]= match t with 
  | Leaf -> `Empty
  | Node(x, l, r) -> match (is_bst' l, is_bst' r) with
    | (`Failure, _) -> `Failure
    | (_, `Failure) -> `Failure
    | (`Empty, `Empty) -> `Empty
    | (`Success(a, b), `Empty) -> if b < x then `Success(a, x) else `Failure
    | (`Empty, `Success(a, b)) -> if x < a then `Success(x, b) else `Failure
    | (`Success(a, b), `Success(c, d)) -> if b < x < c then `Success(a, d) else `Failure
```

By my intuition type signature should be as in annotations, but ocaml infers it as:

```ml
bool tree -> [ `Empty | `Failure | `Success of bool * bool ]
```

Why does this happens and is it possible to fix that?

Comment: What is `i`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: @glennsl whoops, fixed

Comment: try changing `if b < x < c ...` to `if b < x && x < c ...` (if `&&` is how one writes "and" in Ocaml). my *guess* is it is interpreted as `b < (x < c)`, and `x < c` returns a Boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `b < x < c`. It's interpreted as `(b < x) < c`, and since `<` returns a `bool` and requires the type of both operands to be the same, `c` must also be a `bool`.

What you want instead is `b < x && x < c`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `b < x < c` requires that `c` be `bool`:

```
# 4 < 7 < 9
          _
  ;;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type bool
```

Here it says that `9` was expected to be `bool`.

So `c: bool` => `Success(c, d) == Success of bool * bool`.